# cannot find module on expo init

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to work with react native using expo, but I cannot manage to get it work, I installed the expo cli globally and have the latest node version , but I get this message when trying to create a new project:
[image]

Please I'm desperate, what should I do to fix this? I can't find a solution to this

Comment: Can you delete in path of error folder of exp-cli and install it again?

Comment: @Oleg thank you , deleting the folder manually and then installing it again, worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me, is manually go to the NPM global folder, delete expo-cli and then install it again.